# random.choices Выводит квадратные скобки вокруг выводимых чисел

Tags: python

Вот мой код:

```
import random

for i in range(10):
    print(random.choices([0, 1], cum_weights=[10, 1]))
```

Срез пробовал. Не помогло

Comment: Ну да, в документации функции choices чётко прописано, что она возвращает именно список. В чём проблема?

Comment: Звёздочку поставьте и всё: `print(*random.choices(...`

Answer (score 1):

Если хотите получить 1(один) случайный элемент из списка элементов используйте:

```
import random

for i in range(10):
    print(random.choice([0, 1]), end = ' ')
```

`>>>0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1

**random.choice()** возвращает список... но дает ряд возможностей...
подробнее можно глянуть [тут](https://www.bestprog.net/ru/2019/11/10/python-module-random-functions-for-sequences-ru/)
Ставить '*'  - значит внести некую неопределенность... по умолчанию k = 1, но кто его знает какие умолчания в вашем случае... поэтому делаем определенно.

```
import random

for i in range(10):
    print(random.choices([0, 1], cum_weights=[10, 1], k = 1)[0])
```

Отмечу, что в таких весах никакой случайности не будет. Всегда 100% ноль... Для 50/50 поставьте cum_weights=[1, 2]